# CountIf function doesn't work properly in VBA function, but works in sub

Tags: excel, vba

I have been writing a function that counts bank transactions by transaction codes. However, the countif function doesn't work in VBA Function. Yet, when I run the same set of codes as an independent sub, the function works and returns the correct value.

I've been trying different ways to work around the formula, but I'm still very confused why CountIf doesn't work here.

Thank you very much.
Below are the codes:

```
            Sub Test()

            ' Input Transaction Code

                wirecode0 = InputBox("code1")
                wirecode1 = InputBox("code2")

            ' Pass codes to array
            Dim var()
                var = Array(wirecode0, wirecode1, wirecode2, wirecode3, _
                wirecode4, wirecode5, wirecode6, wirecode7, wirecode8)

            ' Define worksheet and variables
            Dim ws As Worksheet
            Set ws = Worksheets("Banking Transaction")
            Dim colnumbercode As Integer
            Dim totalcount As Integer

            'Locate the column "Type" which contains the transaction codes
                    With ws
                    colnumbercode = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Type", .Range("1:1"), 0)
                    colnumbercodeletter = Chr(64 + colnumbercode)
                    codecol = colnumbercodeletter & ":" & colnumbercodeletter

            'Count codes
                            For i = 0 To 8
                                If var(i) = "" Then
                                var(i) = 0
                                End If
                            totalcount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Range(codecol), var(i)) + totalcount
                            Next i
                    End With
                MsgBox (totalcount)
            End Sub


            Public Function CountbyCode(ByRef wirecode0, Optional ByRef wirecode1, _
                                        Optional ByRef wirecode2, Optional ByRef wirecode3, _
                                        Optional ByRef wirecode4, Optional ByRef wirecode5, _
                                        Optional ByRef wirecode6, Optional ByRef wirecode7, _
                                        Optional ByRef wirecode8)
            ' Pass codes to array
            Dim var()
                                        var = Array(wirecode0, wirecode1, wirecode2, wirecode3, _
                                        wirecode4, wirecode5, wirecode6, wirecode7, wirecode8)

            ' Define worksheet and variables
            Dim ws As Worksheet
            Set ws = Worksheets("Banking Transaction")
            Dim colnumbercode As Integer
            Dim totalcount As Integer

            'Locate the column "Type" which contains the transaction codes
                    With ws
                    colnumbercode = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Type", .Range("1:1"), 0)
                    colnumbercodeletter = Chr(64 + colnumbercode)
                    codecol = colnumbercodeletter & ":" & colnumbercodeletter

             'Count codes
                            For i = 0 To 8
                                If var(i) = "" Then
                                var(i) = 0
                                End If
                                totalcount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Range(codecol), var(i)) + totalcount
                            Next i
                    End With

            CountbyCode = totalcount

            End Function
```

Comment: What does it do instead of working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't advise a value for `wirecode1`, `wirecode2` (etc), they will be assigned a value of `Missing` (Note: not `"Missing"`).

It isn't possible to compare `Missing` with `""` (or otherwise treat it as a `String`) without generating an error.

I recommend you change your loop to test for missing values:

```
For i = 0 To 8
    If Not IsMissing(var(i)) Then
        If var(i) = "" Then
            var(i) = 0
        End If
        totalcount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Range(codecol), var(i)) + totalcount
    End If
Next i
```

---

Note also that you don't need to calculate `codecol` - you can use `.Columns(colnumbercode)` instead of `.Range(codecol)`.

Comment: Thank you! It finally works, and thanks for the suggestions too!